# How to use more than 80 characters in pageLayout section Name

Tags: page-layout, setup

How to use more than 80 characters in page layout section Name in sales force

Comment: Are you hitting some limit on the section name? What is your error message? It is likely that this is a limit controlled by Salesforce so not possible to change. But knowing a bit more about what your attempting to do, why you need so many characters might help folks provide some alternatives perhaps? :-)

Comment: Actually i want to use more than 80 characters in section name but Section Name field give this Error Message "The maximum length for this field is 80" i want to add description about that section as well as name of the section

Comment: I see, how about putting a small VF page component in the section then?

Comment: I do not want to use VF page,is this possible to do that without using VF page

Comment: Maybe a Formula field?

Comment: Sadly however neither will be visible on the edit page however, only viewing.

Comment: No problem, i've posted a summary of this discussion as an answer for you to review.

Answer (score 5):

I can see a few options to this, as per our discussion in the comments. Given your goal to add a description aspect to your section.

- Use a **Visualforce page** to simply host the descriptive text and place that on the layout. You can then also use HTML formatting and images etc if needed.
- Use a **Formula field** to include some message text which you can place in a single cell layout section to maximise the horizontal space to allow the text to flow more.

**NOTE:** That neither of these options, will sadly appear in Edit mode.

Finally, though not directly related to your question, but in relation to make the native UI more descriptive, don't forget you can also provide field level descriptions, which surface as little yellow popups when the user hovers over the question mark icon.

Comment: ,hi can you please tell me how can i use formula field for Some message text with html color and size ,because it is giving some error Message , i searched for that also but didnt get any useful link.

Comment: It looks like this is not possible (I'm not surprised from a security perspective tbh), https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrSLAA0. As I said only the VF route will allow you to use formatting. Other option, it's an ugly one, is to use a Formula field to display an image? (yuke!) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is similar to the Formula Field option provided by Andrew, **but you can have it displayed in Edit mode.**  It's not going to lengthen the section name, but means you can have a description or blurb to help describe the section.

Instead of using a Formula Field with some message text, you create a standard Text Area field and add your message as the Default Value.  Make the field read-only for the profiles that will create these records.

This will result in the field displaying on the page in both Edit and View mode, which can be really handy.

Considerations:

- Won't work for System Administrators as they cannot have read-only access to a field
- Because the message is stored as a value on each record, storage may become an issue
- If the message needs to change for new and existing records, a data update to existing records will be required, as well as an update to the Default Value of that field